# Orthogonal group acts on vector field

Tags: general-topology

I recently had an exam, yesterday acctually, and there was a question that stumped me.

> The orthogonal group $O(n)$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by matrix multiplication, show that the orbit space is homeomorphic to $[0,\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}$

I could logically narrow $\mathbb{R}^n$ to positive coefficients by having a diagonal unit matrix where 1 is replaced by $-1$ and so on, I was very uncertain however how to collapse it down further in dimension so it became homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

How would one go about this exacly?

Answer (score 4):

Note that $O(n)$ preserves the norm of the vector being acted on. In fact any two vectors of the same norm are in the same orbit of the $O(n)$-action, and the orbits are spheres centered at the origin and the origin itself.

Comment: So all vectors $v$ with $|v|=n$ would be equivalent to $w=\{n,0,0,0,0,....\}$?

Comment: @MattSamuel Thanks.

Comment: Oh . . . I knew I was missing sonethingvsimple!  Very nice;  ***endorsed!***